# Get data from object composition

Tags: php, object

Let's say I have 3 objects : "Place", "Person", "Action".

Depending on the place where is the person and the age of this person, this person can do different action.

For example :

```
$place->person->action->drive(); // OK if place is "parking" and "person" is 18+
$place->person->action->learn(); // OK if the place is "school" and person is less than 18.
```

**How can I access the data about the objects "Person" and "Place" from the Action class ?**

Classes examples :

```
class Place {
    public $person;
    private $name;

    function __construct($place, $person) {
        $this->name = $place;
        $this->person = $person;
    }

}

class Person {
    public $action;
    private $name;
    private $age;

    function __construct($name, $age) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = $age;
        $this->action = new Action();
    }
}

class Action {
    public function drive() {
        // How can I access the person's Age ?
        // How can I acess the place Name ?
    }

    public function learn() {
        // ... Same problem.
    }
}
```

I think I could transmit "$this" from Person to Action when I create the Action Object (ie. $this->action = new Action($this)), but what about the Place data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to make Person a property of Place nor Action a property of Person.

I'd be more inclined to create public *getters* for Person and Place's properties and either make them injectable properties of Action or at least pass them as arguments to Action's methods, eg

```
class Place
{
    private $name;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

class Person
{
    private $name;
    private $age;

    public function __construct($name, $age)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = $age;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getAge()
    {
        return $this->age();
    }
}

class Action
{
    private $person;
    private $place;

    public function __constuct(Person $person, Place $place)
    {
        $this->person = $person;
        $this->place = $place;
    }

    public function drive()
    {
        if ($this->person->getAge() < 18) {
            throw new Exception('Too young to drive!');
        }

        if ($this->place->getName() != 'parking') {
            throw new Exception("Not parking, can't drive!");
        }

        // start driving
    }
}
```